# Issue PHP mail header

Tags: php

I have the following issue when using php mail, I'll expose the two ways I do it and wich result I get and expect:

Case 1:

```
$to = $EmailsPropiosPresupuestos;
$subject = $txtAsuntoCliente;
$message = $emailCliente;
$headers .= "From: noreply\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

The email i sent and the html decoded in the correct way, but my "From" header looks like: "noreply@124512.net" (Strange root).

Case 2:

```
$to = $EmailsPropiosPresupuestos;
$subject = $txtAsuntoCliente;
$message = $emailCliente;
$headers .= "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Now my "From" header is fine, "noreply@example.com", but the mail doesn't decode the html, so I can't view the message in the correct way.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to send the message with the html decoded, and with my "from" header with the correct email adress "noreply@example.com", and I can't do both things.

Comment: Try changing `\r\n` to just `\n` - sometimes mail clients act funny with `\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the MIME version to your header:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

For the no-reply I suggest you to add it using the `Reply-To`:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@example.com\n";
```

This will allow you to keep a better from email address.
And In my code I use `\n` on each header line and **finish** with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

from: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Example #4 Sending HTML email

It is also possible to send HTML email with mail().

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```